# Passing string variables to a javascript function via ahref

Tags: php, javascript, html

So I have some php code that is generating links, and for the url I'm trying to pass the data to a javascript function.

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:SubmitRemoval('", urlencode($item->roomname), "')\">Remove</a><br/>";
```

In the javascript function I am using this, but it does not seem to be removing the url encoding crap.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitRemoval(roomname)
    {
        alert(decodeURI(roomname));
    }
</script>
```

I'm not really a javascript pro, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you need unescape not decodeURI

Comment: Don't use javascript href values. Use a real href and onclick attribute, or a UI element that doesn't pretend to be navigation when it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can work.  You are encoding with PHP and trying to decode with javascript.

Comment: that's right, either you have to create a function that encodes and decodes the same way in php and js (which is a decoder/encoder created manually) or you have to avoid encoding from php and decoding from js since they both use different decoder/encoder